# Create object from objects in two different arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I have two different arrays of objects. The objects in both arrays have different properties. I want to go through both arrays and grab the properties I want, then create a new object with the combined properties. I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Here is what I have so far.

So basically.

Objects in array1 have two properties I need. rim and joints

Objects in array2 have one property I need. attributes

I want to build a new object so that it has rim, joints and attributes.

```
var projectWheel = {};

var wheels = [
    {
        property1: value,
        property2: value,
        joints: [],
        rim: {
            property1: value
        }
    },
    {
        property1: value,
        property2: value,
        joints: [],
        rim: {
            property1: value
        }
    }
];

var virtualMachines = [
    {
        property1: value,
        property2: value,
        property3: value,
        attributes: {
            property: value
        }
    },
    {
        property1: value,
        property2: value,
        property3: value,
        attributes: {
            property: value
        }
    }
];

var ExportVM = function (wheel, virtualmachine) {
    var SpokeVM;
    var newSpoke;
    var commonArray = [];

    projectWheel.spokes = [];

    SpokeVM = function (vm, spoke) {
        // data here
    }

    $.each(wheel.spokes, function (key, spoke) {
        commonArray.push(spoke);
    });

    $.each(virtualmachine, function (key, vm) {
        commonArray.push(vm);
    });

    $.each(commonArray, function (key, data) {
        var spoke;
        var virtualmachine;

        if (data.rim) spoke = data;
        if (data.attributes) virtualmachine = data;

        newSpoke = new SpokeVM(virtualmachine, spoke);
        projectWheel.spokes.push(newSpoke);
    });
}

ExportVM(wheels, virtualMachines);
```

Expected object to be created

```
{
    attributes: {
        property1: value
    },
    rim: {
        property1: value
    },
    joints: []
}
```

Comment: Doesn't explain a specific problem and you haven't provided proper description of what is expected (final results). Also need sample input

Comment: Does adding sample input and expected result make this more clear? I'm not sure how to ask this more specifically. I have two arrays with objects and I want to loop through the arrays and build a new object using specific values from the objects in both arrays.

Comment: Of course it does when we don't know if arrays are same length, or if structure matches your code. Many people stumble over structure issues. Also allows people to test the code

Comment: @visualbam If the solution requires you to pass a array with desired properties and then it gives you back the combined result in one object, Is that fine?

Comment: @visualbam your expected object is little confusing as you have the same properties in 2 objects within the same array and which one does your final object consider ?

Comment: @Reddy So theres two arrays.

Objects in array1 have two properties I need. rim and joints
Objects in array2 have one property I need. attributes

I want to build a new object so that it has rim, joints and attributes.

Comment: @visualbam yes I understood that but my confusion was in your first array you have 2 objects and you want the properties rim and joints, But of which object, is it from the first object or second ?

Comment: @Reddy Oh, so I'm getting the data back from a server and need to do this for every object. I only put two for brevity sake. Both arrays will always have the same amount of objects inside of them.

I need to do some sort of logic by looping through these arrays and puzzling the properties together.

Comment: @visualbam Ok so here is my final understanding, You want the data from every object and you will have 2 arrays every time, the number of objects inside each array may change But both the arrays will have the same number of objects, Finally you want to combine two arrays into 1 array and the objects inside this final array would be the combination of    1st object from both arrays, 2nd object from both and so on...

Comment: @Reddy Exactly! Thats the end result I'm looking for.

Comment: @visualbam Ok give me sometime, I will be back and I will give you the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution.

```
var requiredProperties = ["attributes","rim","joints"]  //set all the required properties that you want to retrieve

function GetProcessedObjectArray(wheels,virtualMachines,requiredProperties){
   var arraySize = wheels.length;
   var finalArray =[];

   $.each(wheels,function(i,v){
     var currObj = {};
     $.each(wheels[i],function(key,value){
        if ( $.inArray(key, requiredProperties) > -1 ) {
          currObj[key] = value;
        }
     });
      $.each(virtualMachines[i],function(key,value){
        if ( $.inArray(key, requiredProperties) > -1 ) {
          currObj[key] = value;
        }
     });
     finalArray.push(currObj);
   });  

   return finalArray;
}


console.log(GetProcessedObjectArray(wheels,virtualMachines,requiredProperties));
```

Take a look into this [Working JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/tLt1dpdx/2/)

Comment: wow.. I'm extremely impressed, this is beautiful. I'm beyond grateful.

Comment: Glad that works for you. Happy coding !! Keep in touch

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks again.. this gave me a much better understanding on how to construct objects in a loop.

Comment: @visualbam glad to hear that. Thanks for the appreciation.